# Powershell removing characters from string up to last separator

Tags: string, powershell

I have a string

Projects\TestEnvironment\11111xx\1111111

and need to get 1111111 from it. What I'm doing now is:

```
$name = $dir.Substring($dir.IndexOf('\')+1)
```

where $dir is my string, however it only removes up to first string, is it possible to change direction?

Comment: Just another one : `$name = $dir -replace '^.*\\',''`

Answer (score 6):

What about using [split-path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path)?

```
$string = 'Projects\TestEnvironment\11111xx\1111111'
Split-Path $string -Leaf
```

returns `1111111`.

Note the `-Leaf` parameter indicates that this cmdlet returns only the last item or container in the path.

Comment: This would also work. `[io.path]::GetFileName("Projects\TestEnvironment\11111xx\1111111")`

Answer (score 3):

@Robin's answer is good if the string is always a path (separated with "\"); in the general case, where the delimiter may be a different character, you can use

```
$string = "This-is-a-string-with-delimiters"
$lastword = ($string -split "-")[-1]
```

The `-split` operator defaults to splitting on a space, but will split on any character you choose to pass it, returning an array of strings, each string being the material before/between/after delimiters - in the example above, each word would be in a separate string in the array. Negative subscripts to an array count from the *end* of the array rather than the start, and are 1-origin rather than 0-origin - so `$x[-1]` is the *last* element of the array `$x`.

This technique also works on paths;

```
$path = "C:\Users\JSmith\Documents\Resume.doc"
$filename = ($path -split "\\")[-1]
```

will give you `$filename` -eq `Resume.doc`. Note that the delimiter passed to `-split` in this case is escaped, because the delimiter can be a regular expression, and the backslash ("\") is meaningful in regular expressions (it's the character that indicates that another meaningful character is to be "escaped", or its meaning ignored).

Comment: These appear to be for directory paths so the delimeter probably is not going to be in question in _this_ case. Note that split supports regex so your last example would fail.

Comment: @Matt - Good catch; I'd forgotten that `-split` supports regular expressions. Fixed/updated.

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
('Projects\TestEnvironment\11111xx\1111111' -split '\\')[-1]
```

or

```
'Projects\TestEnvironment\11111xx\1111111'.Split('\')[-1]
```